# Print execution time of function in seconds?

Tags: clojure

```
(time(get_report))
```

Gives me "Elapsed time  32038 ms". But I want seconds, not ms. How can I accomplish this in Clojure?

I want it to print like "Report took 32 seconds".

Update on how I have it now:

```
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
   expr."
{:added "1.0"}
[expr]
`(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
     ret# ~expr]
 (prn (str "Report print time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime))   start#)) 1000000000.0) " secs"))))

(time(get_report))
```

This is my gather_report function:

```
(defn gather_report []

(def list_of_isbns (split_isbns "src/clj_amazon/isbn_list.txt"))
(get_title_and_rank_for_all_isbns list_of_isbns)
)
```

Comment: Just create a custom version of the macro. Look up the source and see how they did it. I created my own version that returns the time instead of printing it. Takes like 10 seconds.

Comment: And don't use `def` inside a function! See my answer to see why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard definition:

```
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
 expr."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ~expr]
     (prn (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)) 1000000.0) " msecs"))
     ret#))
```

Note the division form? Just divide by 1000 to convert to seconds. You can change the message aswell:

```
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
 expr."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ~expr]
     (prn (str "Report print time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)) 1000000000.0) " secs"))
     ret#))
```

The best way to find the source of something is to look up the Clojure docs for the function, and follow the" source" link.

And this is why you don't use `def` inside a function definition:

```
(defn test-fn [] 
    (def some-val 20)
    (* some-val some-val)

(test-fn)

(println some-val) 
; prints 20!
```

`def` creates a global value. You certainly don't want that! Use `let` instead to limit the scope:

```
(defn test-fn [] 
    (let [some-val 20]
        (* some-val some-val))
```

Comment: I added (:refer-clojure :exclude [time]) to exclude the time macro. And then redefined it. But i keep getting the error "Wrong number of args(1) passed to time"

Comment: this is my call. (time(get_report))

Comment: @lalakers4life You must have pasted the definition weird. Make sure the argument list of the macro takes 1 argument

Comment: hmm.. I updated my question. Can you take a look and see what I'm doing wrong? I feel like I'm really close.

Comment: @lalakers4life I can't reproduce that. Try restarting your REPL/clean your IDE. I just got called into work unfortunately, so I won't be able to look at it until later. Sorry.

Comment: @lalakers4life If you get rid of the `refer-clojure` bit, then just rename your version of the macro, do your still get the error?

Comment: yup. I'm trying to figure out how to use clj-time instead. but I don't know how that's working out right now

Comment: Why are you using `def` inside of a function? Definitely do not do that! Use `let` instead. Probably not your problem, but needed to be mentioned.

Comment: @lalakers4life See the edit to my answer to see why your shouldn't use `def` inside a function.

Comment: Also, Ive tried, but can't recreate your problem. It must be an environment issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a modified version of [time macro](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3754) tailored to your needs:

```
(defmacro sectime
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (. System (currentTimeMillis))
         ret# ~expr]
     (prn (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (. System (currentTimeMillis)) start#)) 1000.0) " secs"))
     ret#))
```

Comment: I've updated to the issue I'm having right now. I keep getting "Wrong number of args(1) passed to time"